# Azure Function SQL input binding fails on AddAsync

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-functions

I struggle with a rather simple function that is supposed to add a record to an Azure SQL Server table. The following example throws:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: AddUser.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter newLicenses after function returned:.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql: Unexpected error upserting rows. Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'downloadDT', table '_____.dbo.license'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log,
    [Sql("dbo.license", "SqlConnStr")] IAsyncCollector<License> newLicenses)
{
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddLicenseBody>(requestBody);

    var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var newLicense = new License()
                         {
                             emailKey = userInfo.emailAddress.ToLower(),
                             downloadDT = DateOnly.FromDateTime(utcNow),
                         };

    log.LogInformation("inserting to dbo.license", newLicense);
    await newLicenses.AddAsync(newLicense);
  
    var licensesAdded = new List<AddLicenseBody> { userInfo };

    return new OkObjectResult(licensesAdded);
}

public class License
{
    public string emailKey { get; set; }
    public DateOnly downloadDT { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? installDT { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lastverifyDT { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? uninstallDT { get; set; }
    public int? deactivated { get; set; }
    public string deactivationReasonID { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? expiryDT { get; set; }
}
```

The SQL table is:

```
CREATE TABLE license
(
    emailKey NVARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
    downloadDT DATE NOT NULL,
    installDT DATE,
    lastverifyDT DATETIME,
    uninstallDT DATE,
    deactivated BIT,
    deactivationReasonID NVARCHAR(256),
    expiryDT DATE
)
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you look at the generated query with parameter values?

Comment: how do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue. Seems like I can't use DateOnly data type to bind with SQL Server's DATA. Instead I need to us DateTime object and use its .Date property:

```
// ...

var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

var newLicense = new License()
{
    emailKey = email,
    downloadDT = utcNow.Date,
};

// ...

public class License
{
  // ...
  public DateTime downloadDT { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```